# QGIS coloring of label background based on variable does not work

Tags: qgis, labeling, color, variables, background

I want to change the background color of particular labels from my layer to mark them. Therefore I use a CASE structure inside the expression editor, that corresponds to this filling color. See first picture. As seen in the preview (7), the CASE structure produces the required color string and the coloring works fine.

[image: first picture]

To make later color changes for all marked labels easier, I want to use a variable, instead of hard coding the color in every 'WHEN ... THEN ...' line. Therefore I defined a variable `myColor` in the variable dialog of the layer properties of this layer. See second picture.

[image: second picture]

But when I use this newly created variable in the expression editor, the coloring suddenly does not work any more. See third picture. Strangely enough, the prieview (7) still yields the right expression and when copying it from there back up into the CASE structure, it works again. I have already tried several things like

- using different kinds and numbers of quotes when defining and using the variable
- converting between different data types, like int and string, while using the variable
- using the function `color_rgba(255,255,0,255)` and using seperate variables for the rgba values
- using the functions `var()` and `eval()` to try to get and evaluate the value by force.

[image: third picture]

What am I doing wrong?

I am using QGIS 3.32.2-Lima.

Comment: Indeed, I can reproduce this. Seems to be a bug...?